# Validating Empty Json using wix/accord

Tags: json, scala, playframework

How can I validate empty json using wix/accord

I have done research and found https://github.com/wix/accord/issues/58.

But, It is not the case I want.

For example: 
 I have a class

```
  case class Test(name:Option[String], subject:Option[String])
```

I have my validator

```
object TestValidator{
val validateTest = validator[Test] { p =>
p.name must notEmpty
}
```

It works when name is not provided.

But if I send empty json as

```
{ }
```

It response with None.get error

Comment: What do you use for JSON deserialization? Can you just log the object you get back from deserialization of `{ }` and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't use JSON at all? I suspect that the result type of the deserialization of `{}` in your case is not what you expect i.e. not `Test` and thus validation does not report any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `must` validator is appropriate here. Try using `is`.

```
object TestValidator{
    val validateTest = validator[Test] { p =>
    p.name is notEmpty
}
```